# USPS Label api image generation failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, usps

I m using usps api in asp.net . after sending shipment confirmation I got response:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <DelivConfirmCertifyV3.0Response>DeliveryConfirmationNumber>420063719101969010386000074165</DeliveryConfirmationNumber>
 <DeliveryConfirmationLabel>
```

> 2q/+mEH/8IP/wQPSU+zna52BhiD/1T4YX//6
>   FJqEGnDXww/9U//hEnJuH  e9ecC/+GD/
>   /////8EtsMO+iN/Mkcwf+YWMfNp9Eb/+YY/5gdEb/m04N8wf//5tP8wf62ww/ovv
>   g35+///FF9/8G+19F9/8G/z9/////4i2236+z8Tz2fv/s/X2fvr/7PxeferP3X9n
>   7zE/Z+///7P3/Z+/cMP+u6V7pNpa7pMMJOl+ra+6V/7petpOl9+6TaTaX/7pe2rp
>   Nrk3rVht/a9q2tra2vanJjtftbX7VteO17W1tfbXtbW1//tftbW1OXbbF9iUP2KY
>   pimKYlD9itpivYlD2P2KYraYrYlD4pivYrYpimK//Yr2NimP02w/abwwmEGEGE14
>   YWGEGF7TYZb/DCYXhhbTczhBhewsMIMIML/8MLwy3hhBlv9NsPxERERERERERERE
>   RERERERERERERERERERERERwm239Nw/1sN/SbYXzWHITN53YyUGR8qiPZ2BZFdJs
>   Nfvwg11/CCbDX56B4ovnOtREEU8ukm2v4fQTfoRaTj/b0m/BhJN/8+eby+aZwz+R
>   2R8z6c8Z/LmEDL5vI7L5dm2ZjCBmM+Z/LmajJzP5HI0y+fM0Okr/thB/4QcfqIQc
>   X8emEwn4QcWEGEHH4TCDQIvoJv/o2P20kbHNzSpGxy7YYLm4SoE8OfmGC0bHLto2
>   NGxzY0tGto2PcJN/+n/6f/p6f+mnSf6enp6f/punEUm/+k39qk3V+t1/VVj+t14p
>   N1a6TpNpP//96/dLp///Bfp/h/vXj6Tf/j++P////zwn/7I+H3/Ggr//7pe3///+
>   ERv//YP3S/Ct/+fT/Pp0myH///8///wefT/zl23/S/tL/1///0v/8iL7S8z9Nv/3
>   797fdWv///9r5Rve//ab/0nM//cz+KbV6///X3r73M//bScz02v4WGEvYqGEvbCV
>   r//9hftfbShhLYrtYYSCdfiExX7FbsUxX//sQRH4PYr2Niv2KYpEO9r8INe0Gugw
>   gwv//abfDC9hBraw0Gkm2viIiIjiIiIiIiIiIiIiIiIpNwvpIJsf4Sb+CSV/pJ+d
>   lzKgOfilRERAopUQSIFFvkRETOxSb4QcP/Kr5A/OedmPIf+0307/11111/YTfReO
>   af//H//2m/T7f////7V8ff////9p//nyJyNCz5Zdk5Z0InIIPLmaEEGUQQZ0efIn
>   I0I6xczQggzSPR6LxHZwj8XZTkfiOzhH49G4uZo8IPLmaEU5E7z7Lx8sW//hBhNB
>   4QcQ0HhBhB8WEH+E8INBhB6YQf/GEHoMIOMIP9MJ/FoNBhPCeg9vhLXRsaLto1vR
>   scu2jW9F20XcMKTho2MMLDCRcDRd0a2i7cSoaLuGFry+NjiVDRscvi7/EqGi4GGF
>   Jw0a2jW0XA0XA0a3t8EtLSerSfSfdJ+npvp0n/p6bSenp6b3hEfrSenSfpv6en6d
>   J0np6dJ9v3H+k6Tf9NpN+KTfX/6TpNpN41pN//X039JN/Wk/Wk2k2k6TpN7fO0lW
>   Pj+P/8P/x///4f/2rrj+P///////5lxGZGmbI0M0z+aF9uFhePC/HsH/4X//jYP/
>   +r8L4X///+OP/jyDEJGa0aCEuk09NP0zszM9k+CZ1X5qpwL+cC/4YP/zgX//wwf/ v9ZmF8kBf//////h62qNbRraSNbR7aQVGthB/a/9Eb+YHRG/5tIN/+iN///MMf/6
>   v6I3+iN////8xcwf+bZXn+PPz6dBN9Ok3qgm584z2/ndd+i+5+9F9/wb/9F9//8G
>   //urXRffRff//////2/b0m99JvfCBEf3Sb9v9r9f2fuv7P2UT//X//2fi8//v9df
>   1////2frP3/Z+/9/x19IVrHQh+390v1bSdL1tJ0u9tL/X9tW0nSv9tL//W0tdtLX
>   21/dJ0m1bV0vy+R8vmMu0HtnjQZtnv+vy50Pghl2bzGR3yC9hm2e/GcvtbW17W1t
>   dtbX+1/tbW1bX7XimPtbW17W1+1/tbW1tbX+L9P8J6f6X+n6QQvi9vT+1+xKHsUx
>   WxKHxTFbFMVD9iUPh8NjYpimK9iob+xKHwiONiUP2KYlD/Y4fsUxTGxKHsV/BcSo
>   bC9GtsJGhj//Eq3+E+W72QrthI0MeGF+02GEGFtNzOEGFsIMJ/abfcMt4YQYTC8M
>   J+tpvYTTeGE1+GW9/DCDCDLeGsML0q6f+n6/SS+m0tIL03tv18RERERERERERERE
>   RERERERERERHERERERERERERHHj+v8fSb9L+n9Jen79Jv5X6+F//r/6X/+kn/x//
>   0ucj/+cF4/CX/+Egh//H9tf//0CI//pJf6WkiDo/zj//Ff/+qNnnUNJBbaTaXoJB
>   F+d3+r865V4YX//1X9ql2tr6SC+/6b/iP//rr2c2KRDjpimKS0Q+ygJtZxxaWt9n
>   P//+la7aTXtBr+rSw2ulG2l//4cUxBEfhsZvEREREUmK2KimGxm/mVma47EX/701
>   uwtINbIcdU7C+pP/iIiIiIiI0ItiGRFwvQJf0m2vX+k7X//ba//08LnZIQQYQeXM
>   0I6xdk5E5ZxnCJ2Xj5atjwg/i0HoMIMJ6QQYT0H1fRdwwgwpOGjW4lQ0bGi7ekjY
>   0XA0a37+m/p0np0nq9JJ6dJ9J+k39aTdN+k+l6TpN/f///x8Yof/9///H4Xwvx/f
>   ///Nhez4X/3//8wPojfzPRG/5mg////+i+5+7Rff/f//2fvr/ev7P3/bS/3StLVt
>   LvVtXS+/a/9ra2trt2tranLNYcvkCRFckyJdGMigQjMvlaKwRTyNkRbIoFJYZ0Mz
>   PsVw/YqERxsSh7FbsSh7EoexX+uEGvfhB6uE/TTT4YW/hhbCabDC7abDWGF85HFG
>   54z+8UbnXz4xnUzQ0aGjQ+IiIjiIiIiI4j/pN+3pPfpBvp6en+d0v84ZmYQZHyOz
>   ZnMuzeeOnMZHYQZHzxnMu9zx5fL5/NmcyOR/ps4ZzLtTGR2R8vG4+YQcgmHctHOG
>   cyOR/I+eM+edDMzPaTaTaTf9L9NPjT09NK4h+np7af+nHpCE9Pj00wn3p4px+mnp
>   p///21/RraNDDCm40OJUPRoe81wwtGhxKh+jW/bSRrc2NLQIj0SoYbmwSnEp2jWw
>   wpEhxKhsNGtzY0tGho1vRraNbH//8VyFigm0n6Sbp9J/q/Sbp/QTf+gm6/TI9T9U
>   09P03TyPgm6/SdBNyEgJtBN///DC/+h+nr6H9/p6////b9Mj9d9ViF0nrDD//of/
>   ///iPORj///////j9tKP0tD+P82L/5qce2l8c6Bx/////////////2/D//om//wb
>   ///////Oj//+v///OjtpTo/gjv//QL/8z+dFtL50+dBwn//////t1//+l//6Tf//
>   16////////+z3Zz+1/s52uv2v/Z7/7Pex2lfzj/9e19vs9/9nOz32e7PbaTaTaX/
>   bSdfbS/dW0rS9tL8JNpexTaXtqx/f9rFpfYSbS2K3VtLbSbStbW1/Id7GxUPYr9i
>   mKioexXxTH+x7TFP7f7HIRxXsUx/sUx7Gxm+KOcVFf9hNPtftBhTjp9r6YXtMLww
>   n9v9lw3a8NMLa2mFsJhYaw0GviIiIiIiI4iIiIiIiI4hxGxERFIRERERERERERH/
>   ttpf0rbX+FbbS/03aXxFthhL7sNftsMJftkM/r7YYhfba+219sML7hhfLcM2wwud
>   pMkzKDMGR4qw5riBxG2Q2Rkbjt4yEgYMRNLQOwYLrqvD852v52k/9EHFWUhdUCI8
>   gSBd+tr+v+gbY9fqhmnEfxxztFjoG3//2+CI/OP/9EMsC9Um/3+1//YNvow/wgwg
>   zEXj95iI7Lx8j8R2XggyPH7/PEfs6ETkfiOM/F4+RoR1i7JyNCCDPETsvHy8uZoR
>   +I7OEdY8R1i5mhbINQR9L/9tL48IOP/3rCD8INBxBEfrCaD0GEGEHhBhPQfFoONB 4QemEHsG30tJsMIMLbS1l9Rd5fQwm0u10bH6Lto1uXjXRdtGtxKhou6LthhI2NFw
>   NGt8nDRrcvzW9F24lQ0XfkNZO////pfTf//6T/TpP/1aT09N0+k9Ok/TpPpP09PT
>   ewbfS//bSjrSbr/3//xSbp60nSbptJvH9J0m+tJukm/GtJvZCuQaA/S0m/2Kr//b
>   S7Sx/h/2vj//Dx////+H/7ZwM1vpcf/C////wvsHH/8f+weF+P+Pj2D/9wYO/ENP
>   9qar///+bC+GD96//wweeC///4YP/2ygM1v/+n//7aW2lojf4Nzaf+YHTZy/bSbORx4QL9cOq+H661j/x/9
>   RUfFbFfxUV+x1XIr+RX8W1/IsC2OpFcciwLYrimKkVx9Re1xUX4QJJJfeulaIe0l
>   1qiHG6STpJJXtSKOkmkmkkkkWOkWOkkkmvSpJKkkmE0kklTCaap6YTSTTVOk0wkq
>   SaYSWEC6pbD69h8dr117Jv/egwmF4YWGF/hrDX7LfVYfw/hhBhfhwwmW8GEHZN4c
>   MIMLDCDCDsm/BhBIDEgMCBSDQo+Pg0Kc3RhcnR4cmVmDQoyOTM3MA0KJSVFT0YNCg==
>
> ```
> </DeliveryConfirmationLabel>
> <ToName>Tom Collins</ToName>
> <ToFirm>XYZ CORP.</ToFirm>
> <ToAddress1>Suite 4D</ToAddress1>
> <ToAddress2>8 WILDWOOD DR</ToAddress2>
> <ToCity>OLD LYME</ToCity>
> <ToState>CT</ToState>
> <ToZip5>06371</ToZip5>
> <ToZip4>1844</ToZip4>
> <Postnet>06371184408</Postnet>
> </DelivConfirmCertifyV3.0Response>
> ```

and I used following code to generate pdf file from its byte:

```
 byte[] labelBuffer = encoding.GetBytes("i put here inner string of DeliveryConfirmationLabel");
    string fileSaveLocation = " d:/test.pdf";
    // Save label buffer to file
    FileStream LabelFile = new FileStream(fileSaveLocation, FileMode.Create);
    LabelFile.Write(labelBuffer, 0, labelBuffer.Length);
    LabelFile.Close();
```

`pdf` created but contentof pdf is not opening why? Can any one help?

Comment: While I cannot say for sure, `encoding.GetBytes()` may be your issue. By the looks of it you probably want `byte[] labelBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String("inner string");`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Do u got a any solution for Base64 Conversion from XML and create PDF?
please help me here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21326635/how-to-decode-base64-returned-xml-from-usps-api-and-create-pdf-file-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9157514/usps-label-api-image-generation-failed
may be help full

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle image as a Base64String, which is what it is.

```
byte[] labelBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String("i put here inner string of DeliveryConfirmationLabel");
```

And I don't think that it is a pdf, it's an image. So try this code instead:

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, 
    imageBytes.Length);

  // Convert byte[] to Image
  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
  Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
  return image;
}
```

Comment: the base64 portion is correct, but the image may be either pdf or gif depending on the requested format. so pdf might be fine.

Comment: Error at "Image.FromStream() method..any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Save it in pdf.

> $response = curl_exec($session);
>
> $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($response);
>   $label_img = $xml->DeliveryConfirmationLabel;
>
> $label_title = 'label.pdf'; // give your filename
>
> $file=fopen($label_title,"w");
>
> fwrite($file,base64_decode($label_img));

**Explanation:**
$response is received from USPS api call, which you made to get the encoded label. Just get this label in a variable "$label_img" and then save it on disk. $label_title is the name of the file being saved. fopen and fwrite are php commands.

Comment: Please be more verbose. Say what your code does, otherwise there's little chance your answer will be considered (and upvoted.)